# Ошибка отправки уведомления Bitmessage

Tags: php, laravel, daemon

помогите пожалуйста с решением вопроса

На сайте установлено Bitmessage оповещения. 
Пользователю приходит уведомление о  новом сообщении, новой продаже и так далее

Если пользователь не установил у себя в настройках аккаунта Bitmessage адрес, 
то при написании ему в личку через интерфейс сайта,
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбивает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

BitmessageNotify.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Marketplace\Bitmessage\Bitmessage;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class BitmessageNotify implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $tries = 2;
    /**
     * Content to send via bitmessage
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * Message title
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Bitmessage address to send content to
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $address;


    /**
     * Marketplace address
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository|mixed
     */
    private $sender;


    private $bitmessage;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $title,string $content,string $address)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->sender = config('bitmessage.marketplace_address');
        $this->bitmessage = new Bitmessage(
            config('bitmessage.connection.username'),
            config('bitmessage.connection.password'),
            config('bitmessage.connection.host'),
            config('bitmessage.connection.port')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->attempts() <= $this->tries){
            $this->bitmessage->sendMessage($this->address,$this->sender,$this->title,$this->content);
        } else {
            $this->delete();
        }

    }
}
```

Dispatchable.php

```html
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Bus;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher;

trait Dispatchable
{
    /**
     * Dispatch the job with the given arguments.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch
     */
    public static function dispatch()
    {
        return new PendingDispatch(new static(...func_get_args()));
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch a command to its appropriate handler in the current process.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function dispatchNow()
    {
        return app(Dispatcher::class)->dispatchNow(new static(...func_get_args()));
    }

    /**
     * Set the jobs that should run if this job is successful.
     *
     * @param  array  $chain
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain
     */
    public static function withChain($chain)
    {
        return new PendingChain(static::class, $chain);
    }
}
```

PendingDispatch

```html
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Bus;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher;

class PendingDispatch
{
    /**
     * The job.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    protected $job;

    /**
     * Create a new pending job dispatch.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $job
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($job)
    {
        $this->job = $job;
    }

    /**
     * Set the desired connection for the job.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $connection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function onConnection($connection)
    {
        $this->job->onConnection($connection);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the desired queue for the job.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $queue
     * @return $this
     */
    public function onQueue($queue)
    {
        $this->job->onQueue($queue);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the desired connection for the chain.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $connection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function allOnConnection($connection)
    {
        $this->job->allOnConnection($connection);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the desired queue for the chain.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $queue
     * @return $this
     */
    public function allOnQueue($queue)
    {
        $this->job->allOnQueue($queue);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the desired delay for the job.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime|int|null  $delay
     * @return $this
     */
    public function delay($delay)
    {
        $this->job->delay($delay);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the jobs that should run if this job is successful.
     *
     * @param  array  $chain
     * @return $this
     */
    public function chain($chain)
    {
        $this->job->chain($chain);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the object's destruction.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        app(Dispatcher::class)->dispatch($this->job);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,  как решить данную проблему, что необходимо прописать в коде, 
чтобы если пользователь,  вдруг у себя в настройках  не установит Bitmessage адрес, 
на скрине ниже пользователь как раз не установил себе Bitmessage адрес
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная ошибка при написании ему в ЛС не выходила,
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а просто доставляла сообщение пользователю, игнорируя то что он не указал Bitmessage адрес,(возможно вообше не знает что это такое или не хочет им пользоваться)

P.S если пользователь установил себе Bitmessage адрес в настройках 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то  ошибка при написании ему в личку не появляеться.

Comment: Если `$адрес == null` подставляйте пустую строку `''`

Comment: извиняюсь, не совсем понял, куда необходимо подставить "$адрес == null подставляйте пустую строку ''

Comment: Там, где у вас вызывается конструктор класса в котором происходит ошибка

Comment: не получаеться http://prntscr.com/nwc0hl     Прикрепил все затрагиваемые коды выше.